# Windows 8 reports WRONG uptime (possibly total Hybrid-Boot uptime)

Tags: windows-8, uptime, hybrid-boot

[image: Wrong Uptime]

The up time shown in the picture is 6 Days, 1 hour, 34 Minutes, 22 seconds. I turned on this Laptop just about 7 min ago.

I actually think it like, Windows 8 reports the total up time while in Hybrid-Boot mode. How do I get the real up time?? Also, why does Windows reports it that way??

Is there any way to get the real up time in GUI way (for my n00b friend)??

---

**UPDATE:** I disabled Hybrid-Boot and rebooted. It now results the right uptime. Also, doing a full shutdown with `shutdown /s /t 0` also works.

---

---

**Little more explanation**, My question is that How to get the actual up-time (time from when we powered the system on) even if the Hybrid-Boot is enabled? Possibly in stock Windows without any external program, though not necessary.

---

Any explanation to this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "real up time"? What did you do 7 minutes ago exactly?

Comment: Real up time means the actual time from when I turned on the system. (That's what I did 7 min ago, turn on the Laptop!)

Comment: The legacy definition for uptime is the time that the computer has been running since the kernel initialized itself. Since hybrid boot is just a special type of suspend (there was previously suspend to RAM and Hibernate), it doesn't count as "shutting down", because the same instance of the Windows kernel is used.

Comment: @allquixotic True, That's why I thought it would be Hybrid-Boot up time.

Comment: I guess you din't actually got the Question. I want to ask that how to get the actual up-time even when Hybrid-Boot in enabled. I am updating the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to get an out-of-the-box solution to find out the uptime of your machine since the last hybrid shutdown / fast startup took place, right?

You can get this information (as provided by @allquixotic) from the EventLog using PowerShell like this:

```
PS c:\> Write-Host $("{0:c}" -f ((Get-Date)- (Get-EventLog -LogName system -Source "Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter" -Newest 1).TimeGenerated))
```

To embed powershell command into a Windows shell script you can do this instead:

```
c:\> powershell.exe -nologo -command Write-Host $('Time since last ''Fast Startup'': {0:c}' -f ((Get-Date)- (Get-EventLog -LogName system -Source \"Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter\" -Newest 1).TimeGenerated))
```

Howerver, to get this to work out of the box, you could set it into a permanent environment variable like this instead:

```
c:\> setx HardwareUptime "powershell.exe -nologo -command Write-Host $('Uptime since last ''Fast Startup'': {0:c}' -f ((Get-Date)- (Get-EventLog -LogName system -Source 'Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter' -Newest 1).TimeGenerated))"
```

so, you can then get it to work by opening up a `cmd` window and doing:

```
c:\> %HardwareUpTime%
```

**UPDATE:**

I just found today that using the above entry in the event log will also take into account "Sleep" or suspend mode, so running `%HardwareUpTime%` will tell you the elapsed time since the PC resumed from sleeping if you let it do so.

Therefore, here it is:

```
setx HardwareUptime "powershell.exe -nologo -command Write-Host $('Uptime since hardware boot: {0:c}' -f ((Get-Date)- (Get-EventLog -LogName system -InstanceId 27 -Newest 1).TimeGenerated)); Write-Host $('Uptime since system resumed: {0:c}' -f ((Get-Date)- (Get-EventLog -LogName system -Source 'Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter' -Newest 1).TimeGenerated));"
```

I've modified the command a little bit to be more explicit and give you both pieces of information:

- Elapsed time since Windows booted (either after a hybrid shutdown, full shutdown or simple reboot or hibernation).
- Elapsed time since Windows resumed execution (after returning from sleep mode).

*NOTE:* If the system didn't sleep in between, both times will be the same.

Comment: This seems to me like a nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [here](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=684782):

Check the Windows Event Log.

1. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
2. Enter in the box, `%windir%\system32\eventvwr.msc /s`
3. Click "Create Custom View..." on the right-hand side.
4. Set the settings like this: [image: power-troubleshooter]
5. Click OK
6. When prompted, give the custom view a name (this can be anything you want)
7. It will display the list of resume times

Comment: Ok, Its nice. Its somewhat what I want. What if I am a n00b?? Its just not suitable. Also, It results the last **resume** time, for up time I need to minus it from my current time. Is there any direct method for  up time, maybe in command-line?? I am up voting, but not accepting.

Comment: There's no shrinkwrapped solution for this AFAIK. You'd have to write a program. Maybe *I* will....

Comment: Okay, I'll try that later maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable Hybrid-Boot and reboot. It should display the right uptime. Also, doing a full shutdown with `shutdown /s /t 0` also works.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in **Update**

Comment: @AkshatMittal Yes it is, but I figured you'd like to accept an answer :)

Comment: No. -_- The question is that "How to get the real up-time in GUI form?"

Comment: Well, first you would have to disable your `Hybrid-Boot` as uptime starts counting from the time the kernel was initialized.  That's the only way.

Comment: The only way, sure?

Answer (score 0):

this also happens in older Version (XP, Vista,7) when you use `hibernation`. The time gets only reseted when you do a `full boot`, but the Win8 fast startup is no longer a full boot. It is a combination of logging the user off + Hibernation.