# No network connection after resume on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

If I put my Windows 8 computer into sleep mode, there is no network connection after I resume the session. If I re-plug my Internet stick into the computer, it works (but stops if I sleep again).

What I *do* get is that "shutting down" Windows 8 on a desktop, by default, *doesn't* actually shut it down, but *hibernates* it (evident by the boot timestamp being a few weeks in the past and no `POST` beep). For example, Speccy reports that my last *boot* was on April 2, 2013 5:51:49 AM PDT, but today is clearly April 7, 2013.

My network stick is a [TP-Link TL-WN722N](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/TL-WN722N.html). The drivers provided with the CD and [on their website](http://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/?model=TL-WN722N) don't support Windows 8, but plugging in through Ethernet (100ft coax cable for the router) I downloaded the *chipset's* driver through Windows Update allowing it to work.

Here are some of the specs for my setup ([Speccy report](http://speccy.piriform.com/results/ajSEGXoIjtHIlenSePzvkVT)):

- Operating System: **Windows 8 Pro 64-bit**
- Network Stick: **TP-LINK TL-WN722N**
- Chipset: **[Atheros AR9271](http://www.qca.qualcomm.com/technology/technology.php?nav1=47&product=77)** ([datasheet](http://www.qca.qualcomm.com/media/product/product_77_file1.pdf))
- Router: **[Cisco Valet M20](http://www.linksys.com/ca/support-product?pid=01t80000003K7ZWAA0)**

Windows Update (where it downloaded the driver from in the first place) says that I'm up to date, sans hidden "updates" (Bing Toolbar). I doubt this is my router's fault, but I'm not denying the possibility. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 uses Fast Startup (aka Hybrid Shutdown, aka Hybrid Boot) out of the box, which is why it's hibernating instead of actually turning off.

Check out:

- [Difference between shutting down and turning on vs. restart in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/508050/difference-between-shutting-down-and-turning-on-vs-restart-in-windows-8?lq=1)
- [Does Windows 8 really shutdown?](https://superuser.com/questions/568444/does-windows-8-really-shutdown?lq=1)

The problem is most likely that your TP-Link USB stick doesn't support resuming from hibernation properly.

Something to try is the head to the advanced properties of the device (in Device Manager), and adjust how it's power is handled.

Often this type of problem can be resolved by un-checking "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

[image: Device Power config]

Another option may be to [disable the Fast Startup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html).